# Too many errors in R program

Tags: r, read.table

I have just started studying R in second sem of my undergrad. It is hard to figure a lot of things here. I hope if you can point me in right direction?

Initially I was not sure why require lines were giving error, then i figured that they were trying to load packages which were not in my R installation, so i got them on. I also figured out that the data given to me was to be put in a file named auto_mpg.txt. But the errors after that line are hard for me to figure.

Can you please help me understand this?

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Workspace loaded from ~/R/my_project/.RData]

> #################################################################
> #################  NIKITA TIWARI ############################
> #################################################################
> #################  DATA SUMMARY PJ1  ############################
> ##       mpg             cyl              wt           region     
> ##  Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1613   Min.   :1.000  
> ##  1st Qu.:17.50   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:2224   1st Qu.:1.000  
> ##  Median :23.00   Median :4.000   Median :2804   Median :1.000  
> ##  Mean   :23.51   Mean   :5.455   Mean   :2970   Mean   :1.573  
> ##  3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:3608   3rd Qu.:2.000  
> ##  Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :5140   Max.   :3.000  
> ##                                                                
> ##             model    
> ##  ford pinto    :  6  
> ##  amc matador   :  5  
> ##  ford maverick :  5  
> ##  toyota corolla:  5  
> ##  amc gremlin   :  4  
> ##  amc hornet    :  4  
> ##  (Other)       :369
> #################################################################
> #################################################################
> 
> require(gridExtra) #given to me
Loading required package: gridExtra
Warning message:
package ‘gridExtra’ was built under R version 3.4.2 
> require(ggplot2) #given to me
Loading required package: ggplot2
Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.2 
> 
> 
> auto <- read.table("auto_mpg.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE) #given to me
> head(auto)
            mpg.............cyl..............wt...........region
1 Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1613   Min.   :1.000  
2 1st Qu.:17.50   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:2224   1st Qu.:1.000  
3 Median :23.00   Median :4.000   Median :2804   Median :1.000  
4 Mean   :23.51   Mean   :5.455   Mean   :2970   Mean   :1.573  
5 3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:3608   3rd Qu.:2.000  
6 Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :5140   Max.   :3.000  
> summary(auto) #given to me
                                     mpg.............cyl..............wt...........region
 1st Qu.:17.50   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:2224   1st Qu.:1.000  :1                        
 3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:3608   3rd Qu.:2.000  :1                        
 Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :5140   Max.   :3.000  :1                        
 Mean   :23.51   Mean   :5.455   Mean   :2970   Mean   :1.573  :1                        
 Median :23.00   Median :4.000   Median :2804   Median :1.000  :1                        
 Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1613   Min.   :1.000  :1                        
> 
> 
> auto$cyl <- as.factor(auto$cyl)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cyl, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$region <- as.factor(auto$region)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, region, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$cyl[auto$cyl == 1] <- "USA"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cyl, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$cyl[auto$cyl == 2] <- "EUR"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cyl, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$cyl[auto$cyl == 3] <- "ASIA"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cyl, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$region[auto$region == 1] <- "USA"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, region, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$region[auto$region == 2] <- "EUR"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, region, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$region[auto$region == 3] <- "ASIA"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, region, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> 
> auto$cyl <- factor(auto$cyl, levels=c("USA","EUR","ASIA"))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cyl, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> auto$region <- factor(auto$region, levels=c("USA","EUR","ASIA"))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, region, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
> summary(auto)
                                     mpg.............cyl..............wt...........region
 1st Qu.:17.50   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:2224   1st Qu.:1.000  :1                        
 3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:3608   3rd Qu.:2.000  :1                        
 Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :5140   Max.   :3.000  :1                        
 Mean   :23.51   Mean   :5.455   Mean   :2970   Mean   :1.573  :1                        
 Median :23.00   Median :4.000   Median :2804   Median :1.000  :1                        
 Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1613   Min.   :1.000  :1                        
> 
> ###################################################################
> # calculate the mean mpg for cars, broken out by the number of 
> # cylinders in the car.
> ###################################################################
> 
> 
> ###################################################################
> #Provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # write a line describing the purpose of the next code chunk
> ###################################################################
> 
> 
> ###################################################################
> #provide a dsecriptiojn of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # Histograms
> ###################################################################
> # the next chunk of code is creating bar graphs and filling them 
> # with either region or cyl , with count on the y axis and 
> # mpg on the x axis
> ###################################################################
> ggplot(auto, aes(x = mpg, y = count, fill = cyl)) + geom_bar()
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found
> ggplot(auto, aes(x = mpg, y = count, fill = region)) + geom_bar()
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found
> ###################################################################
> # provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # write a line describe the purpose of the next chunck of code
> ###################################################################
> b1 <- ggplot(auto, aes(x=cyl, fill=cyl)) + geom_bar()
> b2 <- ggplot(auto, aes(x=region, fill=region)) + geom_bar()
> ###################################################################
> # the above code is used to creat a specific bar graph and it's 
> # x axis is the same a the fill so that it is more clear
> ###################################################################
> # the next chunck of code is used to fill the graph with the bars
> ###################################################################
> b3 <- ggplot(auto, aes(x = cyl, fill = region)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
> b4 <- ggplot(auto, aes(x = region, fill = cyl)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
> grid.arrange(b1, b2 ,b3, b4, ncol= 4)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found
> ###################################################################
> # provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # the code below is going to make box plots of the data
> ###################################################################
> bp1 <- ggplot ( auto, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = cyl)) + geom_boxplot()
> bp2 <- ggplot ( auto, aes(x = region, y = mpg, fill = region)) + geom_boxplot()
> grid.arrange(bp1, bp2, ncol = 2)
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found
> ###################################################################
> # provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # the code below is going to make box plots of the data spilt into
> # 3, 4, ,5, 6, 8 data with mpg being y axis, region being x axis
> # and region being the fill
> ###################################################################
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ###################################################################
> # provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # the code below is going to a jitter plot so basically its just a 
> # lot dots on a graph
> ###################################################################
> jp1 <- ggplot ( auto, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, fill = cyl)) + geom_jitter()
> jp2 <- ggplot ( auto, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, fill = region)) + geom_jitter()
> grid.arrange(jp1, jp2, ncol = 2)
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'wt' not found
> ###################################################################
> # provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # the code below is going to a jitter plot but separate the graphs
> # into the different regions and only that region shows up on the
> # graph 
> ###################################################################
> fg1 <- ggplot ( auto, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, fill = cyl)) + geom_jitter()
> + facet_grid(region)
Error in facet_grid(region) : object 'region' not found
> fg1
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'wt' not found
> 
> 
> ###################################################################
> # provide a description of what you notice above
> ###################################################################
> # the code below is going to a jitter plot but separate the graphs
> # into the different regions and into different cyl and only that 
> # cyl and that region show up in that graph
> ###################################################################
>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to read in that file? That seems to be the result of `summary(dataset)` where `dataset` is similar to `mtcars`, a built-in `base R` dataset. I believe you should/must consult with your teacher and ask them your question.

Comment: hi Rui, i am trying to do this line by line. above is the result of running the whole code. so for e.g. i am not able to understand why is this error?  > auto$cyl <- as.factor(auto$cyl)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cyl, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, the error messages
`Error in $<-.data.frame(tmp, cyl, value = integer(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 6`
occur because e. g. `auto$cyl`returns `NULL`.

This is because when executing
`auto <- read.table("auto_mpg.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)`
your column names are not named like they should according to your code.
Instead of e. g. `cyl`, the respective column in your `auto` object seems to be `cyl..............`.
So the first thing you should do is cross-checking whether your `read.table` function works as expected and the columns are named as they should.

Furthermore, the error `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found` says that there is no column named `count` in your `auto` object (it is also not mentioned when executing `summary(auto)`). Therefore, I would assume that you have to calculate the values for the column `count` by yourself.

Finally, `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found` aims at the wrong naming of your columns again. This also refers to the following error messages to the end of your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! With R you are learning an important programming language and starting to use a helpful platform. Maybe you want consider to read about [how you can create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [ask great questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Besides when posting code it is always beneficial to know what you want to achieve with your code - I recommend to use `# comments` for each important step.

As @rui-barradas suspects I think there is a problem when reading your data (that is the normal case:) though it is hard to say without a similar example of your data. You could use `head(auto)` and add the result to your question if it's not private data in any way.

However, perhaps you want to use `View(auto)` to check whether R reads your data set correctly and produces a desirable data frame. (You can check by `class(auto)` if it's indeed a data.frame.) If the result is looking ugly (e. g. column names are displayed weird) use `?read.table` and explore how you could customize the options of `read.table()` (e. g. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or `sep = ";"` (i. e. the separator which is used in the data of your *.txt file)) in order to control in which way R will read the data.